# Find min-max of function $f(x, y, z) = x + 2z$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

I need to find max and min (if they exist) of the following function:
$f(x, y, z) = x + 2z$
On the set $C = \{(x, y, z) ∈ R^3: x + y + z = 1, x^2 + y^2 + z =7/4\}.$

I have checked that the Lagrange theorem assumptions hold, so that I can find the critical points solving the following system of equation:

$1-\lambda_1-2\lambda x=0$

$-\lambda_1-2\lambda_2 y=0$

$2-\lambda_1-\lambda_2=0$

$x+y+z=1$

$x^2+y^2+z=7/4$

From (3) we get $\lambda_1=2-\lambda_2$, that I can substitute into (2) but then I am stuck. Could you help me??

Comment: You have $5$ equations in $5$ unknowns. Where are you stuck?

Comment: This can also be solved without Lagrange multipliers: the min/max values of $f$ are those for which the plane $x+2z=m$ is tangent to $C$. You can solve that system of three equations by back-substitution and then use the tangency condition to get a quadratic in $m$.

Comment: Interesting, but could you please elaborate a little more? I don't get the system of three equations to be solved by back substitution

Answer (score 1):

If you subtract the first two equations, you get
$$
2\lambda_2(x-y)=1.
$$
Then $\lambda_2\ne0$, $x\ne y$. From the third equation, $$\lambda_1=2-\lambda_2=2-\frac1{2(x-y)}.$$
Now the second equation is 
$$
0=\lambda_1+2\lambda_2y=2-\frac1{2(x-y)}+\frac{y}{x-y}=\frac{4x-4y-1+2y}{2(x-y)}
=\frac{4x-2y-1}{2(x-y)},
$$
giving us $4x-2y=1$. Subtracting the fourth equation from the fifth, 
$$
x^2-x+y^2-y=\tfrac34.
$$
With $y=\tfrac{4x-1}2$, this becomes 
$$
x^2-x+\tfrac{(4x-1)^2}4-\tfrac{4x-1}2=\tfrac34.
$$
Simplifying, this becomes $x^2=x$. So $x=0$ or $x=1$. This gives us 
$$
y=\tfrac{4-1}2=\tfrac32,\ \ \ \ y=\tfrac{0-1}{2}=-\tfrac12.
$$
And 
$$
z=1-x-y=1-1-\tfrac32=-\tfrac32,\ \ \ \ z=1-0-\left(-\tfrac12\right)=\tfrac32.
$$
So the two critical points are 
$$
(1,\tfrac32,-\tfrac32)\ \ \ \ \text{ and } \ \ \ (0,-\tfrac12,\tfrac32). 
$$

Answer (score 0):

We have that $\nabla f \equiv (1,0,2)$.
The restrictions are $g_1(x,y,z) = x+ y+z -1$ and $g_2(x,y,z) = x^2+y^2+z - 7/4$.
We have hence

\begin{align}
\nabla g_1(x,y,z) &= (1,1,1)\\
\nabla g_2(x,y,z) &= (2x,2y,1)
\end{align}

We hence need to find solutions to $\nabla f(x,y,z) = \lambda_1\nabla g_1(x,y,z) + \lambda_2\nabla g_2(x,y,z)$ that respect the restrictions, that is

$$\left\{
\begin{align}
1 &= \lambda_1+2\lambda_2x\\
0 &= \lambda_1 + 2\lambda_2y\\
2 &= \lambda_1+\lambda_2\\
1 &= x+y+z\\
7/4 &=x^2+y^2+z
\end{align}
\right.
$$

From the third, we get $\lambda_1 = 2-\lambda_2$.
We may substitute back into the first equation to obtain $\lambda_2(2x-1) = -1$ and into the second equation to obtain $\lambda_2(2y-1) = -2$.

Any two of the first three equations imply that $\lambda_2\neq 0$, and hence $2x-1 = -1/\lambda_2$ and $2y-1 = -2/\lambda_2$.
Therefore $2y-1 = 2(2x-1)$, giving $y$ in terms of $x$.

Now the fourth has $z = 1 - x - y$, and with $y$ in terms of $x$ from above we obtain $z$ in terms of $x$.

Substituting it all into the last we get a quadratic equation in $x$. Solve it, and back substitute.

Answer (score 0):

The $xy$-intersection of the two given surfaces $x + y + z = 1$ and $ x^2 + y^2 + z =\frac74$ is

$$(x-\frac12)^2+(y-\frac12)^2=\frac54\tag 1$$

Rewrite $f$ in the $xy$-space as

$$f(x,y)=x+2(1-x-y) = 2-2y-x\tag 2$$

At the extreme values, its normal vector (1,2) matches that of the circle (1), i.e.

$$(x-\frac12):(y-\frac12) = 1:2$$

Substitute the resulting $y = 2x-\frac12$ into (1) to obtain the tangent points (0,-$\frac12$) and (1,$\frac32$). Plug them back into (2) to obtain the respective maximum and minimum,

$$f_{max}(0,-\frac12) = 3,\>\>\>\>\>f_{min}(1,\frac32) = -2$$